# Google Play -- Download link for unpublished app?

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to have a download link for an unpublished app in Google Play? I want to send it out to a few people before publishing.

I know I could just send an APK, but I would like to have it staged first.

Thanks!

Comment: I highly doubt it as it would be a security risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to download apps from a URL directly (the Amazon app store is distributed in this way) the only caveat is that the phone needs to be set to accept non app-store (Google Play) apps.

Comment: One thing that works great for me is to upload the apk to my dropbox account,  than users can either install it via the web from there, or use there dropbox app to install it (you can also control permissions that way).

Comment: I want it to live on Google Play, but just be private... possible?

Comment: @AdamStorr : I guess it is _not_ possible. Though it may seem possible because you can first upload and activate/publish later, this procedure gives you just the possibility to recheck the textual assets and everything. But: I must admit I am not 100% sure. I could swear having read something like "Test again after uploading" in some pre-PlayStore HowTo ...

Answer (score 2):

Google Play now allows you to [publish beta and alpha versions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en&ref_topic=3450986) of your mobile application.

This involves creating a Google Group or Google+ community, and inviting your testers to it.
They can then use a link of the form `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.example.packagename` to opt in to the beta.

They beta/alpha APK will then be available for them to download normally via Google Play.