# Finding my unpublished app in google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded my app in Google play but did not published yet, because I want to test it before publishing through live market. I found by Google that the link

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="packagename"
```

Will proceed me to the app page but its not happening, so I want to know that is there a way to find an unpublished app in market to test it by downloading and installing on mobile phone...

Comment: Unpublished means that it is not yet available on Play, i.e. you can't download it.

Comment: what do you mean by "test"? You can always install the APK to your own device and test it that way, unless you are talking about testing in-app billing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Play -- Download link for unpublished app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690044/google-play-download-link-for-unpublished-app)

Comment: I've just deleted my answer and have posted another answer to the [marked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9690044/588306) with [a new method from google Play](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22502988/588306).

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** find an unpublished app on Play Store.

If you want to test it before publishing, you should **launch a test version**. In order to do that, you can create a private **list of testers**, which will indicate who is authorized to find it on Play Store.

You can find info on how to accomplish that [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213).