# Installing Unpublished Android Application from Google Play

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I have just uploaded an application to the play store . Its in draft mode right now. Is it possible to test it on mobile device by visiting the Play store?

I mean before publishing it, is it possible to get the play store link so that I can download from Play store instead and test on a mobile device, from an account which I have added to the test users list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Play -- Download link for unpublished app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690044/google-play-download-link-for-unpublished-app)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the application page on Google Play until the app is published (even then it takes a few hours to turn up).

Other than that, Google Play links are always in the format:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<your package name>
```

You can sideload (install from adb, or directly from an apk instead of Google Play) a draft apk, and if it is signed right, you can use it to test In App Billing etc.

Comment: You might want to explain what "sideload" means.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to test the draft application run a signed apk on your device. The keystore used should be same as in the uploaded apk at google. If you want to debug the application you can change the default keystore of eclipse to a custom one
then:

Change the keystore password/key password and key alias following the instructions [here](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-change-alias-passwords-of-your-android-keystore/#comment-2408)

Then
Change Eclipse's Preferences -> Android -> Build -> Custom keystore and give path to your new custom keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the apk you created on your phone, do necessary changes, then export a new apk, or  if you wanna use the same listing you have, update its version number, and sign it with the same key you made before.